# Prolog's input/output

Tags: json, prolog, swi-prolog

I'm trying to write a predicate to read and write a JSON file in prolog.

When I ask to prolog the query with my own predicate it responds with this error message, `source_sink foo.json does not exists (no such file or directory)`. 
I don't know why, because `foo.json` exists and is in the directory.

Any ideas or suggestions?

edit 1:

```
json_load(FileName, JSON) :- open(FileName, read, Str),
                             read_json(Str, X),
                             close(Str),
                             json_to_term(X, JSON).

read_json(Stream, []) :- at_end_of_stream(Stream).

read_json(Stream, [X|L]) :-
    \+ at_end_of_stream(Stream),
    read(Stream, X),
    read_json(Stream, L).
```

Comment: Please post some code where you show what you've tried to do

Comment: no i'm not using web site.
maybe i can try with a new installation of prolog.

Comment: so but in this case it will be static, or not?

Comment: the FileName var take the name of the file

Comment: yeah i tried yet but it's not working

Comment: ok ok so now it's working

Comment: but now there is another problem.
if i pass a json object the predicate fail and prolog says "Syntax error: unexpected end of file"

Answer (score 0):

Swap clauses `read_json/2` because you unify free variable `X`with `[]` as if json-file is empty.

```
read_json(Stream, [X|L]) :-
    \+ at_end_of_stream(Stream),
    read(Stream, X),
    read_json(Stream, L).


read_json(Stream, []) :- at_end_of_stream(Stream).
```